# Use Conan to manage runtime dependencies

Tags: c++, plugins, shared-libraries, conan, conan-2

I would like to use Conan to install

1.) an executable application that has a runtime plugin interface

2.) the plugins, which are shared objects that will be loaded at runtime by the executable

The reason why I chose Conan is because I like how the package id helps to prevent binary incompatibility. If you so will, I want to use Conan as a plugin manager.

Some of the plugins may have a large list of dependencies and if the binary packages in the remotes are not compatible to the conan profile I use on the target machine, I need to locally build them with `--build=missing`. This means I have to have a compiler available on the target machine and the build times can be very long.

But what I really want is that the plugins are all compatible to the executable (in terms of settings, options and dependency resolution) and not any local conan profile on the host machine. There is no need to be compatible to a compiler I have installed locally.

Is there any way to achieve this with conan?

Note that currently I maintain the executable and the plugins so I can make changes to the build system if necessary, e.g. add a conan profile as a resource to the executable via cmake for instance if that helps at all. But of course I would prefer a solution that doesn't rely on changes in the executable or the plugins.

Comment: It seems that you might want either some kind of ``package_id()`` removal of settings, or ``compatibility.py`` definition, but it depends a lot on the ultimate goal. I think this might need more elaboration and conversation to understand the use case. The best would be file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, which is better suited for a conversation style.

Comment: @drodri, thanks for the remark. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/23051